Using hyperref creates compile error with custom subcounters
Minimal Working Example
Consider the following code:
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{hyperref}  % Uncomment causes compile error
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{main}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[main,1]{label={$\cdot$}, ref={\arabic*}}
\creflabelformat{maini}{#2#1#3}
\crefname{maini}{Main}{Mains}

\newcounter{sub}[maini]
\crefname{sub}{Sub}{Subs}
\renewcommand{\thesub}{\themaini.\arabic{sub}}

\begin{document}

\begin{main}
\item\label{main:a} A
    \refstepcounter{sub}\label{main:a:1}
    \refstepcounter{sub}\label{main:a:2}

\item\label{main:b} B
    \refstepcounter{sub}\label{main:b:1}
    \refstepcounter{sub}\label{main:b:2}
\end{main}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\cref{main:a}\\             % Main 1
\cref{main:a:1}\\           % Sub 1.1
\cref{main:a:2}\\           % Sub 1.2

\cref{main:b}\\             % Main 2
\cref{main:b:1}\\           % Sub 1.1
\cref{main:b:2}\\           % Sub 1.2

\end{document}

Problem
The above code compiles fine without the hyperref. If it is loaded, however, the document no longer compiles and a cryptic error is produced:
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.20     \refstepcounter{sub}
                             \label{main:a:1}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@ 
l.20     \refstepcounter{sub}
                             \label{main:a:1}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


there is no error from the code after uncommenting hyperref in texlive 2024.  You get the error shown in texlive 2023.

The posted code (with hyperref uncommented) works without error in current latex releases.  For older releases (eg texlive 2023) you can re-order the package loading
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{main}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[main,1]{label={$\cdot$}, ref={\arabic*}}


\usepackage{hyperref}  % Uncomment causes compile error
\usepackage{cleveref}

\creflabelformat{maini}{#2#1#3}
\crefname{maini}{Main}{Mains}

\newcounter{sub}[maini]
\renewcommand{\thesub}{\themaini.\arabic{sub}}
\crefname{sub}{Sub}{Subs}

\begin{document}

\begin{main}
\item\label{main:a} A
    \refstepcounter{sub}\label{main:a:1}
    \refstepcounter{sub}\label{main:a:2}

\item\label{main:b} B
    \refstepcounter{sub}\label{main:b:1}
    \refstepcounter{sub}\label{main:b:2}
\end{main}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\cref{main:a}\\             % Main 1
\cref{main:a:1}\\           % Sub 1.1
\cref{main:a:2}%\\           % Sub 1.2

\cref{main:b}\\             % Main 2
\cref{main:b:1}\\           % Sub 1.1
\cref{main:b:2}%\\           % Sub 1.2

\end{document}

(unrelated I commented out the two mis-placed \\  that generate underfull box warnings)
